# Clear queue on bootstrap close on X

Tags: angularjs, angular-file-upload

I use angular-file-upload for upload file on my server. 
I put everything in the bootstrap modal box.
Everything working nice.

When I select a file for upload and upload them I want when I click on close or X to clear the queue.

I have button CLOSE in the modal footer where I add function for the clear queue

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default button_pv" ng-click="$dimiss(); uploader.clearQueue(); uploader.cancelAll()" data-dismiss="modal">{{'CLOSE'| translate}}</button>
```

And this is working.
But I try to add the same function `uploader.clearQueue(); uploader.cancelAll()` to close on "X", but this function not executed.

```
var clearModalBoxElement = angular.element("#myModal1");
    if(clearModalBoxElement){
    clearModalBoxElement.on("hidden.bs.modal", function() {
        alert('ss');
        $scope.uploader.clearQueue(); 
        $scope.uploader.cancelAll();
      });
    }
```

But alert is calling and show.I also try without `$scope` but nothing happened

here is working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/x0s2rf4m/1/)

Comment: you have a ton of bugs in your fiddle, ensure you fiddle runs without errors first. Check console.

Comment: @Axr man... rly there is no any problem with this BUG... because, my fiddle is only for example to show what i need. Everything what someone who can help need, in this fiddle working. Do you know answer for my question? How to call function in bootstrap modal on X button?

Comment: Debug your code. put breakpoints on the first 3 lines and see if they hit in the first place. Make sure the .on event is bound on the element correctly. If it is, then it should hit. If it doesn't then youre not binding the event on right target.

Comment: When i add alert on button X...and hit X.... alert is showing...

Comment: You're clicking the button so the alert should fire like it does. By doing that all you have done is test the browser, no your code. You need to put a console log or alert before and after the first 3 lines and see if they trigger or not. How do you know that if(clearModalBoxElement) is not false. and the event .on bind doesn't even happen.

Comment: @Axr i will try tomorow  when came back to office